# Skin Detection Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, computer-vision

I have a small data set containing around 80 images for people, and the corresponding ground truth for skin regions. I want to train a classifier to be able to detect a skin, and use it later on my own generated data, but I'm not sure what is the right way to go. I believe it would be hard to train a CNN due to the small number of images. So can someone suggest a direction?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what exactly you would like to detect/classify?

Comment: After training on this data set and being able to detect skin with a reasonable accuracy, I want to use this classifier on another data set of face images, where some of the examples have parts of there faces covered. I want to be able to locate the covered parts. I have tried color based methods, and most were more or less sensitive to variation in illumination, so I would like to try another approach.

Comment: @Sammy To clarify a bit more. This data set has ground truth binary images, where white corresponds to skin pixels and black corresponds to other non-skin pixels. I want to generate such binary images for my face images, to be able to tell which parts of the image is skin and which part is not.

Comment: White corresponds to skin and black corresponds to non-skin? Am I misinterpreting this or are you only concerned about correct classification for fair skinned individuals?

Comment: The goal is to detect any kind of human skin. The output is a binary image, where 1 corresponds to skin (of any color), and 0 corresponds to anything else other than skin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to give transfer learning a try for two reasons:

1. Your dataset is relatively small
2. Skin, faces and similar human body features have been successfully classified or segmented by existing neural networks

Specifically, you might want to have a look at [Skin Lesion Analysis Toward Melanoma Detection](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.05006.pdf). While the tasks were slightly different it did include a segmentation task of Melanomas. Here is an example of what they did:

[image: Lesion Segmentation]

And this is a snapshot of how some of the models performed:
[image: Lesion Segmentation - examples]

*Source: both images are from the paper linked above*

It might be close enough to your task to re-use their networks or some part of it. Once you have found a transfer network, you can vary the degree to which you replace or retrain it`s layers to see what works. Given your relatively small dataset I would not retrain too much but start with the final layers only.

**However**, depending on how exactly your dataset looks like, there might be other tasks (e.g. from security applications where one needs to detect, classify or mask an object (e.g. a person or a face)) which resemble yours even better. Therefore, before digging into a specific model and apply transfer learning I'd do some more research.

Answer (score 2):

You could give it a try. 80 it is not so few. There are some data augmentation techniques that will help you to make the most out of your data. Such us:

- Rotating Images
- Cropping
- Adding a constant small number to each pixel in each channel.

And many more. With these techniques, you should be able to multiplicate the images on your dataset.

Comment: I'll give it a shot then. Do you think it's suitable for this case anyway? The point that my output is the same size as the input (I mean the mask containing skin pixels, except that it has only one channel) gives me an impression that the CNN will be very complex in this case. I have not tried such a case before so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @AmrSherbiny What do you mean that your input is the same size than you output? Your input is an image and output is one type of skin colour right? Dont forget to upvote and mark the answer if you liked it.

Comment: I mean that the output is a binary image, where white corresponds to skin pixels and black corresponds to non-skin. Such that when this mask is multiplied by the input image, only the skin pixels remain while other pixels are removed. (I have upvoted but reputation doesn't allow me to change the publicly displayed score)